# Accessing remote tags file with Emacs

Tags: emacs, ctags, tramp

I use Emacs (run natively in OSX) to edit files (mostly python code) on Ubuntu VMs. I run a VM locally, but also access code on EC2. I recently learned about exuberant-ctags and was able to successfully create a tags file on my local VM. The tags file is fairly large (30 MB). I'm accessing the tags file in Emacs using tramp via ssh. My first question is should I expect the access to take a long time? It takes Emacs a few minutes to load the tags file, even though its pulling the file off of a VM running on the same machine.

The second problem I have is that after the tags file is loaded, Emacs (again, running natively in OSX) thinks that the code base is on my local drive, not on the drive of the VM and so gives me a file not found error. So if function X is defined in file Y, how do I get Emacs to figure out that file Y is on the remote machine, not in my local path?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you mount a shared folder in OSX from the VM so that everything looks local?

Comment: Hi Nicolas,
   Thats not a bad idea. Doesn't help me when I'm running on EC2, but at least this will get me half way there. I actually scp-ed the tags file to my drive and had Emacs open it, but it still took several minutes, so even if the file is local, the performance issues are making using ctags untenable. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You should maybe split this question in two. One for the size and one for the remote vs local problem to have better luck in getting answers.